# Should I create separate console projects for each API

Tags: google-api

I have created a web application which connects with Google APIs.  In the past it only connected with the Google Analytics API.  Now I am making it link with Google Webmaster Tools (GWT).  Some of my existing users may want to opt in to GWT.  And moving forward new users may want to link with just one or both APIs.

Is it best practice to create a separate console project for each API?

During experimentation I modified my original Google Analytics project to support GWT.  But in doing this I found there is no way a user could revoke access to just one API; they would need to revoke BOTH APIs.

I then created a separate project to manage just GWT.  This works fine and all.  But from the user's perspective it makes another entry into their "**Connected Apps**" (see screen shot).

What is the best practice for a situation such as this?

[image]

Comment: Projects are application based IMO.  if your application needs to access Google analytics and webmaster tools then your project in GDC should include those. Other wise your users are going to have to authenticate twice once for each project.

Comment: Thats's ok.  My application is "a la carte" reporting tool of sorts.  Over time I plan to add in YouTube access, as well as access to other webservices.  I imagine user's will only want us to have access to certain services.